# How can I reference another model in a column of my Question model in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails 7, I have a model called **Question**. the questions are answered using dropdowns or radio buttons. The dropdown infos come from another models. I have another models like **Place**, **Unit** etc. I need a column in the **Question** where I can somehow save these models referance or maybe like question_col_model = Place.all. I am trying to figure out how to do but failed.
I can not use anything but models for the dropdowns. Thank you

At first I thought of keeping them in array as postgresql supports them. But they are like snapshots of that instance, I need realtime updates. When the model updates, the dropdown updates automaticaly.
When using @questions to loop, I need to get different models for different questions.

Answer (score 1):

You set up your relationships like this:

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question # so it has a field called "question_id"
end
```

you will have several answers with the same question_id value

Comment: thank you for your reply. When the Question model is in loop to print all of them, different question dropdown menu should get data from different model.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly... yes, some answers will reference question_id 1 and others will reference question_id 2, etc